# Using Paint or Gimp WHERE is the UNSELECT?

Tags: gimp, microsoft-paint

Why with paint and gimp both do I see all these drawing, selecting options and no clear unselect?

Is there a way to unselect any of the drawing or selecting methods then I can go and reselect what i did earlier without drawing another circle when I mean to select it. ?

Comment: This truly is the # 1 problem I have using these tools.  I simply cannot see how to have several elements like a like a circle.  The go back to what I selected before and resize it for example.  I feel like I always have to draw a new line a new circle.  I cannot get back to anything I did.

Comment: Should this be split into two separate questions? One about Paint and one about Gimp?

Answer (score 25):

Under the 'Select' dropdown menu on the top of the page click 'None'. Or Shift Ctrl A is the shortcut. This is just to deselect without another action.

Comment: you can also right-click anywhere on your canvas to bring up the same options available on the menu bar. Just a little tip

Comment: None is disabled for default selection.

Comment: The option "None" is disabled for me too, and Shift Ctrl A don't work.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Photoshop, deselect can be toggled by pressing Crtl + D on Windows and CMD + D on Mac. In the case of Gimp, I normally switch to Move tool to use as a cursor (M) - it works in the same way as PS pointer. Also if you want to deselect an area that you have chosen, ctrl+alt+A would work.

Comment: Please explain in more detail:  In the case of Gimp, I normally switch to a Move tool to use as a cursor(M).  I have gimp up right now looking for Move tool and how to switch to it.  Where is this option?

Comment: Just use the hotkey M and you will select the Move tool. Its not really a true deselect but it acts like the pointer in PS - i.e. allows you to drag and move layers. I don't think there is a true "deselect" in PS either, in the case of PS, when you deselect you are just switching to the pointer tool that behaves like a normal cursor.

Comment: Tools → Transform Tools → Move